# How do I create an object called Sigma?

Tags: r, object

i am relatively new to R and need to create an object "Sigma".

Can anyone give me a concise answer as I feel like Im pulling my hair out?

TIA

Comment: `Sigma <- 1:5` createss an object

Comment: What do you want your object `Sigma` to contain?  Check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for tips on how to get the most helpful answer possible.

Comment: Hi. This is what I have to do " Using the rnorm function, create an object called sigma " I understand that rnorm is (N, Mean  = 0,sd = 0) but then I am confused with sigma .

Answer (score 1):

One approach to create an object is to call the generic of the class of object you want. For example, if you wanted to create a vector, you'd call `vector`

```
Sigma <- vector()
```

Other options include `matrix`, `list` and `data.frame`.

Comment: thanks Ian for the info. I am not sure what sigma needs to be.